# jar files are not being detected

Tags: java

I have a class called **SnmpGet.java** in default package. it needs a jar called **example.jar**. the structure of **example.jar** is `-> degault package-> snmp.class`. now **SnmpGet.java** makes use of this **snmp.class**. So now it works fine because **SnmpGet.java** and **snmp.class** are in default package. But if i move the SnmpGet.java in user defined package  like com.test.Work it is not able to detect jar file. what can i do?

I need to use SnmpGet.java in user defined package only. And the jar is the downloaded one. I can not make changes to it.

Comment: Are you making sure the jar is still in the classpath once you move it to other directory?

Comment: i'm using Eclipse IDE and the jars are in classpath

Comment: Are you sure you built the project?

Answer (score 0):

First, your package does not follow the [java naming conventions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html), no upper cases !

Do you rely on `protected` methods, classes, attributes...etc of snmp class ? If so, then moving your SnmpGet class to another package will cause you to lose these accesses

Comment: yes . in the snmp.class i see lot of protected methods. what can be done

Comment: @user1244331 a 'protected' method is a method with a restricted visibility. Have a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.2.1) for detailled informations

Comment: @user1244331 When you call a method, you need to know if you can. To keep it simple, a 'public' method can be invoked by anyone (SnmpGet or others) whereas a 'protected' method will only be available to classes within the same package or subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call `protected` methods of `snmp.class` then your class has to

- subclass `snmp.class` (`public class SnmpGet extends snmp`) *or*
- be in the same package as `snmp.class`

---

*Moving* the java file from `.` to directory `./com/test/Work` requires to add a `package` statement to the source file:

```
package com.test.Work;
```

Then it has to be compiled (again).

Now, in order to start the application, go back to directory `.` (the one that contains the `com` folder now) and do a

```
java -cp .;example.jar com.test.Work.SnmpGet
```

(use `:` instead of `;` if you use unix)

Comment: in the snmp.class i see lot of protected methods. what can be done

Answer (score 0):

You may please try to add the jar(s) dependencies to your classpath. And import the packages & classes from the jar(s) that you would like to use in your SnmpGet.java file. If you are using NetBeans IDE do the following settings to add your jar(s) to your class path:

1. Right-click on your project folder.
2. Go to Properties -> Libraries -> Add JAR/Folder.
3. Add all the jar(s) files to your classpath.
4. Click on OK to finish the process.

If you are working on Eclipse IDE, you may use the following steps:

1. Right-click on your project folder.
2. Go to Properties -> Java Build Path.
3. Select the Libraries tab -> Add External JARs
4. Add all the jar(s) files to your classpath.
5. Click on OK to finish the process.

Hope this resolves your issues.

Comment: Could you please let me know are you able to add any package/import any class from your jar(s) (which is there in the classpath) to your current class? Also check if you can extend any class from the jar(s)?